# MySQL Query takes very long

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `table1` and `table2` linked on `id` column. `id` column is primary key in both tables. Both tables have exactly the same number of rows.

If I run this query:

```
select id from table1 where column1 = 'x'
```

I get the following results in 0.02 seconds: `1, 85279, 85290, 85301, 102683, 158543, 965139, 1036217, 1036218`

If I then run the query `select * from table2 where id in (1, 85279, 85290, 85301, 102683, 158543, 965139, 1036217, 1036218)`, I get, again, very quick results in 0.03 seconds.

Well, here it comes my problem: if I run the query:

```
select * from table2 where id in
(select id from table1 where column1 = 'x')
```

I get the results in 8,5 seconds!

The question is why? Basically I do the same thing in both cases, so it should take mostly 0.02 + 0.03 seconds, not 8,5 (170 times more).

JOI QUERY EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref                 rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      dw      ALL     PRIMARY         NULL    NULL        NULL                1037890 Using where
1   SIMPLE      dd      eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4           allexxgd_db1.dw.id  1
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE dedict

```
CREATE TABLE `dedict` (
 `senseid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `languageIdentifier` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `partOfSpeech` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `_index` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `writtenText` longtext,
 `lexiconid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1053320 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE dedict_writtenform

```
CREATE TABLE `dedict_writtenform` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `writtenForm` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `writtenFormLength` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

INITIAL QUERY - takes around 8.5 seconds:

```
select * from dedict where id in (select id from dedict_writtenform where writtenform = 'Hallo')
```

JOIN QUERY - takes around 9.5 seconds:

```
select dw.writtenform, dd.writtenText from dedict_writtenform dw join dedict dd on dd.id = dw.id where dw.writtenform='hallo'
```

Comment: Doesn't that search table1 for each record you get from table2?

Comment: Does the inner query, `(select id from table1 where column1 = 'x')` return a whole lot of rows?  Maybe it's taking a while to build up that hash table or something..  Can you post the query plan?

Comment: Provide `EXPLAIN` + **complete** table structures

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that your result set is not indexed by mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: I tried initially with JOIN, but the response time was even worse (9.5 seconds) so I dindn't even mention it in my question.

Comment: I'd be curious about the indexes referenced in the `explain` for the joined version. But yeah, I've been using MySQL on a daily basis for about 10 years now, and I keep getting surprised at how it can suddenly lock up on ridiculously simple queries. It's incredibly fast, up until a certain complexity of DB and queries. Beyond that point the execution times are usually more related to the weather than anything else.

Comment: looking again the blind educated guess is: no index on column1 so that a full table scan is needed.

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe it wouldn't fit the 0.2 seconds on the isolated query.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes: it easily would if `table1` is tiny and `table2` is huge (making another assumption that `table2.id` is not indexed as well though)

Comment: ah, no, ... i should stop reading / writing

Comment: @zerkms nope, TS posts the execution times for both isolated queries. If they can execute separately in 0.2 and 0.3 seconds, he is correct in assuming the combined query shouldn't last more than 0.5 seconds. ***HOWEVER***, in the combined query it's likely that a blind index search isn't sufficient anymore, and MySQL decides to use a temp table. On a slow disk system, or with a full `/tmp` drive, that could easily explain the 10-fold speed decrease.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes there are heaps of layers of caches in mysql and OS. Without plan, structure and statistics it makes no sense to assume anything.

Comment: @Catalin:  Just to confirm - this: `select t2.* from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id where t1.column1 = 'x'` takes 9.5 seconds?

Comment: The query I used with join is (with real table names and objects): `select dw.writtenform, dd.writtenText 
from dedict_writtenform dw
join dedict dd on dd.id = dw.id
where dw.writtenform='hallo'`

Comment: @zerkms and all are rendered useless once MySQL decides to go temp table for the intermediate results. At that point you're suddenly I/O limited instead of CPU/RAM limited, and yeah HDDs are usually 10+ times slower than RAM. This is the only possible explanation I can think of for these results. Still needs the `explain` output though to prove it.

Comment: @Catalin Marcu: provide the `EXPLAIN` + `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to your question.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes "This is the only possible explanation I can think of for these results." --- okay. I prefer to base my answers on facts not on assumptions. But hey, we're here for fun not to help people solve issues.

Comment: Put it to your question in a readable form. Put `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Put the exact query you have performed (since it looks like you've changed your mind)

Comment: Now `SHOW CREATE TABLE` **and** the **exact** query (not modified in any way) (not sure why you ignore something several people asked at least 5 times)

Comment: I don't ignore. It just took me a while to restart :( Sorry for that

Comment: Now it's the query left

Comment: In the initial question I din't want to go deep in the table structure because I thought I was doing something basically wrong. Now, I show the exact tables/queries I'm using, because it seems, something is really wrong. But in essence it's the same.

Comment: `dw.writtenform='hallo'` this predicate is not covered by any index, hence mysql performs fullscan to fulfill it. It makes sense to convert `dw` to innodb and create a single column index for `writtenform`

Comment: So what should I do? Index the writtenform column? Secondly, why then `select id from dedict_writtenform where writtenform='hallo'` runs so quickly?

Comment: 1. Convert it to `innodb`. 2. Create an index. "Secondly, why then" --- I'm really surprised you haven't learned yet that to answer any performance-specific question you **HAVE TO** provide the `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @zerkms: After changing to innodb and indexing: The join query: **Query took 0.0010 sec**. The other query I did not even try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the `join` query:

```
select dw.writtenform, dd.writtenText
from dedict_writtenform dw join
     dedict dd
     on dd.id = dw.id
where dw.writtenform = 'hallo';
```

Under most circumstances, the best indexes for this query would be `dedict_writtenform(writtenform, id)` and `dedict(id, writtenText)`.  Create these indexes and check out the performance of the query.